# SQL JOIN - don't get it

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I can't figure out how to get the results I need. Can someone help?

These are the mySql tables I have:

```
restaurant           menu                  menu_has_dishes             dishes
----------           ----                  ---------------             ------
id (k)        <->    restaurantid          id (k)                      title
name                 id (k)       <->      menuid                      price
                     date                  dishid             <->      id (k)
```

I need to get all menus with their respective list of dishes for a certain day, belonging to a restaurant. Can anyone show me the right SQL query for that and maybe explain it...?

Thanks... :)

Comment: This looks a lot like homework. If it is please add the homework tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT d.title, d.price
FROM dishes d
JOIN menu_has_dishes md ON d.id = md.dishid
JOIN menu m ON md.menu_id = m.id
WHERE m.restaurantid = [[your restaurant id goes here]]
```

This will give you output something like this:

```
-----------
|Fish|1.00|
|Ham |2.00|
|... |... |
-----------
```

So let's break down the pieces of this query:

```
--Tell the database what fields you care about
SELECT d.title, d.price

--Tell it what table to start with, and give it a nickname "d"
FROM dishes d

--join to menu_has_dishes so we know what menus contain each dish
JOIN menu_has_dishes md ON d.id = md.dishid

--join to menu so we know what restaurant has each menu
JOIN menu m ON md.menu_id = m.id

--finally, tell it what restaurant to look at
WHERE m.restaurantid = [[your restaurant id goes here]]
```

Comment: @PaigeCook Glad to know my efforts are appreciated :)

Comment: You can get info from the menu too. Try adding `, m.date` to the first line. If you need to do it only for a single day, try adding `AND m.date = '2011-12-7'` to the end of the query.

Comment: Since all the answers are nearly the same thanks to everyone who contrubited...!

Comment: Errr... sorry, got one more: what if I have more than one menu in my result set from which I need only the youngest? Saying "LIMIT 1" on a sorted result (by date) limits also to one dish...

Comment: There is a way to do what you're talking about, but the answer is complicated and outside the scope of this question. I think you should ask it in a new question. Post a new question, show what your current query is, and then explain that you need to get only the newest menu.

Answer (score 1):

This will returns all the fields in the tables, for restaurant '5' on a date:

```
SELECT *
FROM restaurant r
INNER JOIN menu m ON (r.id=m.restaurantid)
INNER JOIN menu_has_dishes md ON (m.menuid=d.menuid)
INNER JOIN dishes d ON (md.dishid=d.id)
WHERE r.id = 5
AND m.date = '2011-12-07'
```

You might just want this to get the pertinent information:

```
SELECT r.id, r.name, m.date, d.title, d.price
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT res.id, res.name,m.id,m.date FROM restaurant res
JOIN menu m ON m.restaurantid = res.id
JOIN menu_has_dishes mhd ON mhd.menuid = m.id
JOIN dishes d ON d.id = mhd.dishid
WHERE res.id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r.name, m.date, d.title, d.price
FROM
    restaurant r
    INNER JOIN menu m
        ON r.id=m.restaurantid
    INNER JOIN menu_has_dishes md
        ON m.id=md.menuid
    INNER JOIN dishes d
        ON md.dishid=d.id
WHERE
    r.id = 123        -- OR r.name = 'abc'
    AND
    m.date = CONVERT(date,'2011/12/06');
```